# Process large amount of records in apex controller

Tags: apex, leads, governorlimits

I have a scenario where I have to get all the records of leads and find the record count for a particular field value and show them on a visualforce page but the problem is that I have around 5 million records to process and we have a governor limit of 50000 in apex class .

Can any please provide a way to process all these records.

Comment: Thats a lot of records, you might want to do some pre-processing for this. For example run a daily Batch and store results in a custom object or custom setting and show results from that object in your page. However then your page will be showing results that are daily and what you have at the moment may be a bit different.  Also you might add processing logic to Lead trigger to update your custom object each time Lead is updated then you will have your custom object up to date with the results.

Comment: What is the page going to be used for? I can't think of a scenario in which showing a table (or something) with 5 million rows is ever useful.

Comment: Ultimately I ill process the records and find out that how many records contain a specific field value and show that table for field value v/s record count on a visualforce page.

Comment: @Lex We had a similar scenario. For example, we source records from multiple locations. We wanted to know which source was more effective than others in pulling in those records and ultimately know which of those sources led to the most revenue.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to create a Scheduled Batch Class that ran a count of all new Leads that came in per day. For example, this is something similar to what I needed to create for the same scenario:

```
global class BatchCountLeads implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
  global final String query = 'SELECT Id FROM Leads WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY';

  global Integer count = 0;

  global BatchCountLeads() {
  }

  global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
  }

  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {
    for (Leads l : [SELECT Id FROM Leads WHERE Id IN :scope]) {
      count = count + 1;
    }
  }

  global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    My_New_Object__c o = new My_New_Object__c(
      Count__c = count,
    );

    INSERT o;
  }
}
```

All this class will do scan through all records that came in today, count them and add a new record to `My_Object__c` and enter that count into the field `Count__c`.

If you schedule this, it'll run each day inserting the new records. This will at least go some way to future proofing this problem.

As for getting historical data, you may want to consider using a more "dynamic" query which can have the `CreatedDate` modified, perhaps having the query/parameter passed into the Batch class instead of hard coding it in? [This](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093lOIAQ) question on the Salesforce Dev Boards would help in doing that.

You could then just run several batch classes that create one record for each previous day and schedule it going forward for every day, counting the number of records for that day.

If you've been getting Leads in for over 2 years, you'll reduce the number of records you need to query from 5 million + to 730 which is much more efficient.

This might not be the best solution, but it's definitely one worth considering.

Comment: Thanks for the help but that will not work as I have to return the processed value on visualforce page.

Comment: @JiteshGoel That's what this will do, you said in your question you wanted the record count? That will then get stored in a new custom object which you can then query and show on a Visualforce page. Unless I'm misinterpreting something? The idea is that instead of querying the `Leads` object, you'd be querying a custom `Leads_Count__c` object or something similar.